# Oracle 12.2 how to retrieve one record when using NOT EXISTS and TimeStamp

Tags: oracle, logging, union, data-retrieval, not-exists

The query below works with 2 tables, one is GA which keeps the current situation and LOG which keeps the records of all the changes made. It takes the information from the first table if the record meets the requirements, otherwise it looks for the information in the second table (selects the records if they don't exist in the first table)

The query is working but it is not quite doing what I want it to do. At this moment, the second part of the union retrieves one ramdom record, only the one that meets the "where" requirements, but I only want to retrieve the first that I find according to the giving date (DATETS) and only if it meets the requirements of the where conditions.

It works perfectly when logs are recorded in different dates but when it comes to comparing logs in the same day (filtering the query by hours), it fails

This is the query:

> ```
> SELECT ID, EJ, NUM, SIT, FORM, DATEAL, DATETS FROM GA
> WHERE
>   ID = '28'
>   AND DATEAL <= 20200629  
>   AND DATETS <= TO_DATE('29/06/20 23:59:59','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
>   AND SIT = 'C'
>   AND (FORM = 'A' OR FORM = 'H')  
>
> UNION
>
> SELECT ID2, EJ2, NUM2, SIT2, FORM2, DATEAL2, DATETS2
>   FROM LOG  
>   WHERE ID2 = '28' AND DATEAL2 <= 20200629
>   AND DATETS2 <= TO_DATE('29/06/20 23:59:59','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
>   AND SIT2 = 'C'
>   AND (FORM2 = 'A' OR FORM2= 'H')
>   AND NOT EXISTS (
>
>    SELECT * FROM GA
>        WHERE ID = '28'
>        AND DATEAL <= 20200629
>        AND DATETS <= TO_DATE('29/06/20 23:59:59','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
>        AND ID= ID2 AND EJ = EJ2 AND NUM = NUM2)
>
> FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS;
> ```

I have tried many things like:

- implementing a "order by desc" but it doesn't work on the second part of the union but on the "not exists" part, gives an error which requires a "select"
- I've also used "WITH cte AS... " to separate the "not exists" part and no luck.
- When I used "rownum<=1" only retrieves 1 record from all the records in the table, and I would need one from every key so I also discarded it

**The result sets will be something like this:**

GA:

> ```
> 28; 2020; 169; N; A; 20200616; 01/07/20 11:17:42,813626000
> ```

Since it doesn't meet the condition it goes to LOG, in LOG there is the following information for the key:

LOG:

> ```
> 28; 2020; 169; N; A; 20200616; 17/06/20 12:37:07,502968000
> 28; 2020; 169; N; A; 20200616; 17/06/20 12:33:00,806542000
> 28; 2020; 169; N; A; 20200616; 17/06/20 09:59:36,412144000
> 28; 2020; 169; C; A; 20200616; 17/06/20 09:59:29,230713000
> 28; 2020; 169; G; A; 20200616; 16/06/20 11:56:45,129770000
> ```

The query returns:

> ```
> 28; 2020; 169; C; A; 20200616; 17/06/20 09:59:29,230713000
> ```

which meets the requirements, but I want it to evaluate the nearest record according to the given date ('29/06/20 23:59:59'), which is:

> ```
> 28; 2020; 169; N; A; 20200616; 17/06/20 12:37:07,502968000
> ```

and since it doesn't meet the requirements it shouldn't be returned (as it is working) but it shouldn't look up for any other record either. For this key, in this case, it shouldn't return any record

Any idea is highly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you need to_timestamp instead of to_date

Comment: Hi Sayan, I appreciate your reply ! I have tried it and it works the same as to_date, it returns the same record. I will expand the explanation of result sets above

Comment: @rosa You could use a left join with a subquery(second query), so you can filter inside the subquery what do you need to join. with Oracle 12c you could use order by date asc|desc fetch first n rows only, with 11g you could you analytic functions

Comment: At first I have tried with left join but it doesn't do the job.I require either the "left" data or the "right" data. The left join brings all records in left+ right together. In this case "union" does the job because it takes one row from a table or another row from another table according to the key. Using the left join, if the "left" or main table doesn't meet the requirements, it doesn't bring any log.